# Use a custom sendmail binary in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, sendmail

I would like to add an option to "Outgoing Server" that uses a custom local sendmail binary (in my case for [notbit](http://busydoingnothing.co.uk/notbit/)) like it is possible in Evoution:

[image]

Is there such an option in Thunderbird?

(german topic: http://www.thunderbird-mail.de/forum/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=67309)